# How to add jquery plugins using webpack?

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack

I am using webpack with angular 2 for my web appllication i need to add a jquery slider to my app , so i am using a jquery plugin for that .

My webpack config for jquery is

```
new ProvidePlugin({   
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'   
})
```

above ProvidePlugin gives $ and jQuery to all over my app , but i need to import the jquery plugin also to my app

Comment: "import the jquery plugin also" - which plugin are you referring to?

Comment: jquery.waterwheelcorousel

Answer (score 0):

Normally a jQuery plugin would be imported where required, rather than globally.

For example:

```
import 'jquery.waterwheelCarousel.min.js';
```

This will cause the plugin file to be loaded and as jQuery is provided globally, it should cause the plugin function to be made available on the jQuery object (`$("#carousel").waterwheelCarousel()`)

If you want to made it globally available instead, look at https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry

Answer (score -2):

in main.ts include

```
import 'jquery';
```

once.

then in webpack config

```
   new ProvidePlugin({
       jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
       $: 'jquery',
      'window.$': 'jquery'
    })
```